# How to set click event to all the anchor tags and display the related div with less script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more than 4 anchor tags.

For example:

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open_popup">Click me 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 3</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 4</a>
</div>
```

Each anchor tags have a click event and that will display the related div image.

```
<div class="click_content_1">
    <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<div class="click_content_2">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_3">
    <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_4">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/fe6/midsummer-fields-1-1394719.jpg">
</div>
```

On the page load, I am hiding the div

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   
$(".click_content_1,.click_content_2,.click_content_3,.click_content_4").hide(); 
          $(".open_popup").click(function(){
            $(".click_content_1").show();
             });
        });
```

Now When User click on "Click me 1" then It will display the image.

Now my issue is, How to set click event to all the anchor tags and display the related div with less script? but hide the previous one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click_content_1,.click_content_2,.click_content_3,.click_content_4").hide();
  $(".open_popup").click(function() {
    $(".click_content_1").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open_popup">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Click me 4</a>
</div>

<div class="click_content_1">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<div class="click_content_2">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_3">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_4">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check updated snippet below....

```js
$(".open_popup").click(function() {
    $($(this).data('rel')).show().siblings(".contentBox").hide();
});
```

```css
.contentBox {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-rel=".click_content_1" class="open_popup">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-rel=".click_content_2" class="open_popup">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-rel=".click_content_3" class="open_popup">Click me 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-rel=".click_content_4" class="open_popup">Click me 4</a>
</div>

<div class="click_content_1 contentBox">1
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/1m.jpg">
</div>

<div class="click_content_2 contentBox">2
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/2m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_3 contentBox">3
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/3m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_4 contentBox">4
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even better, you could do that using link index (eq), so if a link is the third in the list, you'd be looking for the div that's also the third in its pool.

Comment: @Ravenous This solution is a lot safer and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Archer, I got a four answer, Now I am confused which is the best to use. Any help in this also?

Comment: @Ravenous this solution provide dynamic target div identifier, you can set your target div selector in source tag

Comment: @user9437856 I was typing an answer myself that I didn't bother posting because it's pretty much this or the answer from SwapNeil.  I'd definitely go with an answer that has an image reference in the link's data attributes.  You can't break that without trying, whereas using an index is very easily broken.

Comment: @SuperUser, Can you explain me why you use data-rel=".click_content_1" with dot(.)

Comment: @user9437856 It's the class name of the image that's associated with the link.  Basically, "show this image when this link is clicked"

Answer (score 1):

> Try this.. by updating your html using `data` attribute to anchor tag and using one common class for click content..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click_content").hide(); // hide all content div

  $(".open_popup").click(function() {

    $(".click_content").hide(); // hide all content div

    var dataTarget = $(this).attr('data-target'); // Get the target element from data attribute
    $("." + dataTarget).show(); // Show the related div to anchor tag 
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="click_content_1" class="open_popup">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="click_content_2" class="open_popup">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="click_content_3" class="open_popup">Click me 3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="click_content_4" class="open_popup">Click me 4</a>
</div>

<div class="click_content_1 click_content">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<div class="click_content_2 click_content">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_3 click_content">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>


<div class="click_content_4 click_content">
  <img src="https://galleria.io/wp-content/themes/galleria/dist/images/demo/4m.jpg">
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByTagName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // something to do
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to anchors (technically you can do $('a') but it's not nice) and to the elements they're supposed to show. In this case I used 'to_click' for the first and 'click_content' for the others. Create a "class naming system". Then I would do something like:

```
$('.click_content').hide();

$('.to_click').each(function(idx) { $(this).click(function() {
  $('.click_content_'+idx).show();
});
```

I wouldn't use siblings or children unless you're absolutely sure about the structure of your HTML and that you won't change it anytime in the near future, and also that you're not creating code that will be used still for a long time and maybe recoded in two years - but if you do, the thought process would be the same.

Comment: I know this works with the code in the question, but if the links ever end up in a different order then it will stop working.  I'm just not a fan of using indexes to identify other elements.

Comment: @Archer yeah, I agree with you and I would probably not do this either if I wasn't trying to be quick to answer and was thinking of it from no code. Was a bit thrown out by the original code as having an element on a second place with a class with a lesser number would not make sense to me. I'll leave the answer either way because with your comment I actually think it's helpful if anyone stumbles upon this question.